# Django [AssertionError: 401 != 201]

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, factory-boy

I'm writing tests for my API. Now i want to test post method.

Here's my `views.py`:

```
class TaskViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Task.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.TaskSerializer
    authentication_classes = (BasicAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, permissions.IsAdminUser)
```

Here's my `tests.py`:

```
class UserFactory(DjangoModelFactory):

    class Meta:
        model = User

    username = 'dima'
    password = 'moonmvm2k14'
    email = 'admin@admin.com'
    is_superuser = True
    is_active = True
    is_staff = True


class TaskFactory(DjangoModelFactory):

    class Meta:
        model = Task

    title = "TASK N1"
    description = "smth"
    person = factory.SubFactory(UserFactory)
    deadline = date.today()


class ViewTest(APITestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.task = TaskFactory()

        self.username = 'myuser'
        self.password = 'test' 
        self.email = 'admin@mgmail.com'

        self.admin = User.objects.create_superuser(self.username, self.password, self.email)

        self.client = APIClient()
        self.client.login(username=self.admin.username, password=self.admin.password)

    def test_post_task(self):
        url = '/task-list/'
        json_tasks = serializers.TaskSerializer(self.task)
        data = json_tasks.data
        response = self.client.post(url, data)
        tasks_count = Task.objects.count()
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        self.assertEqual(tasks_count, 2)
```

But when i try to test it i see this error:

`AssertionError: 401 != 201`

I don't know why my test fails with Not Authorized Status Code.

So, what's the problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: It seems the `/task-list/` URL is giving you HTTP 401, can you print out the response body and add that to the question?

Comment: You need to print `response.body` to get the body string

Comment: 'Response' object has no attribute 'body'
buy if you want to see response.data,
here is:
'detail': ErrorDetail(string='Authentica[59 chars]ed')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue origins from the way you simulate login in the test case.

You are using the `login()` method of the `APIClient` class, which is suitable when you have `SessionAuthentication`.

From [the docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#loginkwargs):

> The `login` method is appropriate for testing APIs that use session authentication, for example web sites which include AJAX interaction with the API.

---

But in your view you use `BasicAuthentication` ([which is actually only suitable for testing purposes](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#basicauthentication)), so you may use another method of the client class - [`force_authenticate`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#force_authenticateusernone-tokennone):

```
class ViewTest(APITestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        ...

        self.client = APIClient()
        self.client.force_authenticate(user=self.admin)
```

This would make your admin user actually logged in and the status code assert should pass successfully.